# Combine .width() and .resize() into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can combine this JS code? I now have a duplicate code and don't know how to combine the window.width() together with the resize function. The function must execute under 1100px and on resize under 1100px.

```
if($(window).width() <= 1100){

// do something if window is less than 1100px

$(window).resize(function() {

// I have the same code here now a above! How can I combine it?

});

} // end window.width()
```

Comment: Are you saying that there's some code you want to run immediately if the window already smaller than 1100px and would also like to run it if they user resizes the window to such a size? If so, just create a function.

Comment: Yes, indeed and the solution of @MikeC works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to invert your logic:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {

  if($(this).width() <= 1100){
   // do something
  }

});
```

additionally you can add both  ***`load resize`*** events like above.

If you want to trigger it also on ***DOM ready*** than:

```
function myResizeFunction() {

  if($(window).width() <= 1100){
    // do something
  }

}


$(myResizeFunction); // Do on DOM ready
$(window).on("load resize", myResizeFunction); // And also on load and resize
```

Comment: This solution works. Thanks a lot for helping me out. I understand JS better now!

Comment: @Bob Thx! I'm glad this helped! Keep going with JS and Happy coding